# querySelectorAll with custom library

Tags: javascript, object, frameworks, css-selectors

I have this code:

```
(function() {

var base = function (elem) {

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(elem);

    return {
        elems: elements[0],
        on: function (evt, func) {
            if(this.elems) this.elems.addEventListener(evt, func, false);
            return this;
        }
    };
};


window.base = window._ = base;

})();
```

And I can do this:

```
_('form').on('submit', uploadImage);
```

But if i do:

```
_('form').appendChild(input);
```

i get an error: `Object #<Object> has no method 'appendChild'`

So how can i use `_('element')` with native functions and still make it work with the methods in my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your object an `.appendChild` function that calls the `.appendChild` on the element.

```
(function() {

    var base = function (elem) {

        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(elem);

        return {
            elems: elements[0],
            on: function (evt, func) {
                if(this.elems) this.elems.addEventListener(evt, func, false);
                return this;
            },
            appendChild: function(el) {
                this.elems.appendChild(el);
                return this;
        };
    };


    window.base = window._ = base;

})();
```

---

Side note. If you're only interested in the first element returned from `querySelectorAll`, you can use `querySelector` instead.

```
return {
    elems: document.querySelector(elem),
    on: function (evt, func) {
      // ...
```

Comment: Ok but then i have to do this for each native function i want to use. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @Jojje: Not really. The native method is going to rely on a proper calling context. You may be able to reduce code a little by creating the functions in a loop, assuming their behavior is fairly similar, but this will rely on getting the native methods from some source, like an existing element. I don't know what that effect that will have when attempting to share the method with other elements. Safer would be to just create them manually.

Comment: Ok guess i could add a function like: 

`function s(elem) {
    return document.querySelector(elem);
}` and use that when i need native functions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with prototype ([not recommended](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)):

```
// Prototype.js style
var Base = function (selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
};

Element.prototype.on = function (e, f) {
    this.addEventListener(e, f, false);
    return this;
};

elp = Base('#result');
elp.on('click', function () {
    console.log(this);
});

elp instanceof Element; // true
elp.innerHTML; // text
```

Or with an object wrapper:

```
// jQuery style
var Base = function (selector) {
    this[0] = document.querySelector(selector);
    return this;
};

Base.prototype.on = function (e, f) {
    this[0].addEventListener(e, f, false);
    return this;
};

elj = new Base('#result'); // internal new called in jQuery
elj.on('click', function () {
    console.log(this);
});

elj instanceof Base; // true
elj[0] instanceof Element; //true
elj[0].innerHTML; // text
```